# Python - Mocking a ZipFile

Tags: python, testing, mocking

I am trying to get further into testing with python and right now I am hard stuck at trying to write a test for the following code:

```
def get_files(zip_path: Path):
    archive = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', zip_path))
    python_files = []
    for x in archive.filelist:
        if x.filename.endswith(".py"):
            python_files.append(x)
    return python_files
```

The test I came up with looks like that:

```
@mock.patch('zipfile.ZipFile')
def test_get_files(mock_zipfile):
    mock_zipfile.return_value.filelist.return_value = [zipfile.ZipInfo('py_file.py'), zipfile.ZipInfo('py_file.py'),
                                                       zipfile.ZipInfo('any_file.any')]
    nodes = get_ast_nodes(Path('/dummy/path/archive.zip'))
    assert len(nodes) == 2
```

But I am not able to get the test to pass nor do I have any idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is looking this up, i might also add the answer. This is how I got it to work:

```py
@mock.patch('zipfile.ZipFile')
def test_get_files(mock_zipfile):
    mock_zipfile.return_value.filelist = [zipfile.ZipInfo('py_file.py'), zipfile.ZipInfo('py_file.py'),
                                          zipfile.ZipInfo('any_file.any')]
    nodes = get_python_files(zipfile.ZipFile("dummy"))
    assert len(nodes) == 2
```